# nginx permission denied when attempting to access Puma socket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

I'm running my rails application using Puma, and am trying to make my nginx configuration point to it. I'm getting the following errors in my nginx error log:

```
2016/05/15 15:18:41 [crit] 1611#0: *31 stat() "/home/rails/acceptable-trader/current/public//index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 66.253.181.206, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "trade.acceptableice.com"
2016/05/15 15:18:41 [crit] 1611#0: *31 stat() "/home/rails/acceptable-trader/current/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 66.253.181.206, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "trade.acceptableice.com"
2016/05/15 15:18:41 [crit] 1611#0: *31 connect() to unix:///home/rails/acceptable-trader/shared/tmp/sockets/acceptable-trader-puma.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.253.181.206, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///home/rails/acceptable-trader/shared/tmp/sockets/acceptable-trader-puma.sock:/", host: "trade.acceptableice.com"
2016/05/15 15:18:41 [crit] 1611#0: *31 stat() "/home/rails/acceptable-trader/current/public/500.html/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 66.253.181.206, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///home/rails/acceptable-trader/shared/tmp/sockets/acceptable-trader-puma.sock/", host: "trade.acceptableice.com"
2016/05/15 15:18:41 [crit] 1611#0: *31 stat() "/home/rails/acceptable-trader/current/public/500.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 66.253.181.206, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///home/rails/acceptable-trader/shared/tmp/sockets/acceptable-trader-puma.sock/", host: "trade.acceptableice.com"
2016/05/15 15:18:41 [crit] 1611#0: *31 connect() to unix:///home/rails/acceptable-trader/shared/tmp/sockets/acceptable-trader-puma.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.253.181.206, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///home/rails/acceptable-trader/shared/tmp/sockets/acceptable-trader-puma.sock:/500.html", host: "trade.acceptableice.com"
2016/05/15 15:18:41 [crit] 1611#0: *31 stat() "/home/rails/acceptable-trader/current/public//index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 66.253.181.206, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "trade.acceptableice.com"
2016/05/15 15:18:41 [crit] 1611#0: *31 stat() "/home/rails/acceptable-trader/current/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 66.253.181.206, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "trade.acceptableice.com"
2016/05/15 15:18:41 [crit] 1611#0: *31 connect() to unix:///home/rails/acceptable-trader/shared/tmp/sockets/acceptable-trader-puma.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.253.181.206, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///home/rails/acceptable-trader/shared/tmp/sockets/acceptable-trader-puma.sock:/", host: "trade.acceptableice.com"
2016/05/15 15:18:41 [crit] 1611#0: *31 stat() "/home/rails/acceptable-trader/current/public/500.html/index.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 66.253.181.206, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///home/rails/acceptable-trader/shared/tmp/sockets/acceptable-trader-puma.sock/", host: "trade.acceptableice.com"
2016/05/15 15:18:41 [crit] 1611#0: *31 stat() "/home/rails/acceptable-trader/current/public/500.html" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 66.253.181.206, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///home/rails/acceptable-trader/shared/tmp/sockets/acceptable-trader-puma.sock/", host: "trade.acceptableice.com"
2016/05/15 15:18:41 [crit] 1611#0: *31 connect() to unix:///home/rails/acceptable-trader/shared/tmp/sockets/acceptable-trader-puma.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 66.253.181.206, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///home/rails/acceptable-trader/shared/tmp/sockets/acceptable-trader-puma.sock:/500.html", host: "trade.acceptableice.com"
```

I've tried changing the acceptable-trader-puma.sock and its parent folder to be owned by www-data, but that didn't seem to do anything.

My nginx site file is:

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/rails/acceptable-trader/shared/tmp/sockets/acceptable-trader-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /home/rails/acceptable-trader/current/public;
  access_log /home/rails/acceptable-trader/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/rails/acceptable-trader/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Those errors are being caused due to the fact nginx doesn't have permission to access those folders. If you changed user via

chown -R nginx:nginx /folder/path

and that still doesn't work then it is more likely a SELinux error. As a quick work around you could try

setenforce permissive

This is not recommended but it is a test to see weather it is SELinux related or not. If it works after that you need to edit your SELinux Policy to allow nginx to have correct permissions to access those folders. This link here isnt for puma but still a good read on how to fix this error:
[nginx error 13](http://axilleas.me/en/blog/2013/selinux-policy-for-nginx-and-gitlab-unix-socket-in-fedora-19/)

Comment: I'm getting "The program 'setenforce' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: apt-get install selinux-utils" when I try setenforce permissive, which makes me think I don't have SELinux installed. Also I gave the sockets folder permission: drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 May 15 14:48 sockets

Comment: Alright, I did all my chown commands as group:user, instead of user:group. Doing it right solved it. Thanks for trying to help me though!

Answer (score 1):

Was facing same issue. Solved with following

Set permissive mode with setenforce 0 then
add nginx semodule and enable SELinux again with setenforce 1;

`sudo setenforce 0
sudo yum install -y policycoreutils-{python,devel}
sudo grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M nginx
sudo semodule -i nginx.pp
sudo setenforce 1`